# Vala: using a library won't work: taglib, tag_c.h not found

Tags: c, linux, dependencies, vala, meson-build

So I am tinkering with making an app for elementary os that uses the taglib library. Currently I installed the library to `'/usr/include/taglib/'` but when I try to build my app with `sudo ninja install` it says that it can't find the `'tag_c.h'` file in the compiled c code of my app. This `'tag_c.h'` file can however be found in the above directory.

The important parts of my meson file look as follows:

```
dependencies = [
    dependency('gio-unix-2.0', version: '>=2.20'),
    dependency('granite'),
    dependency('taglib_c')
]
...
executable(
    meson.project_name(),
    code_files,
    dependencies: dependencies,
    install: true
)
```

I get no errors building my app when I remove the lines of code that actually use the TagLib library:

```
 TagLib.File f = new TagLib.File(path);
```

So maybe this means that it finds the vapi, but cannot find the c code for it?

First of all, how do I solve this problem?

Second of all, is this just a problem on my machine? How do I make sure that other people who install my app also install taglib by just meson building it and have it work right away?

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS is based on Debian/Ubuntu so I think you need to install `libtagc0-dev` as well. That includes the relevant pkg-config file and C header to use the C interface of TagLib.